# What's the best way to store websocket connection in golang

Tags: websocket, go

I wrote a web chat app, using websockets. It uses one connection per page to push new messages to online users.

So, there are a lot of `websocket.Conn` to manage. I'm currently using a map.

```
onlineUser = map[int] *websocket.Conn
```

I am very worried about the map when 1,000,000 pages are open.

There is a better way to store all the `websocket.Conn`?

---

Erlang's inner database can be used to store an erlang socket.

For Go, I had considered using "encoding/gob" to cache the socket in memcached or redis. But then before using the `websocket.Conn` it but be GOB decoded and that will consume too much CPU.

Comment: Once you have 1e9 concurrent connection you will have different problems.

Comment: A map is a hash table internally. I wouldn't worry too much about it's performance as the Go developers did a good job here. (Did you benchmark, anyway?)

Answer (score 3):

1,000,000 concurrent users is a nice problem to have. :)

Your primary problem is that the websocket spec requires the connection to be maintained open. This means that you can't serialize and cache them.

However, if you could GOB encode them, and every user sent one message a second (unrealistically high IMO) a million GOB decodes per second isn't going to dominate your load.

Also a map can easily handle a million entries.

If you really want to worry about future scaling, figure out how to get two instances of your application to work together on the load. Then increase that to N instances.

Comment: I don't see the point in even gob encoding them since the box still has to keep the TCP connection open.